# How to save Parse installation objectId ( or devicetoken ) as a cookie using Swift

Tags: swift, cookies, parse-platform

I have added Parse to my iOS Swift app and can push messages to my test phone. Now I would like to be able to save the Parse installation objectId as a cookie to pass this information to my server.

After many hours of searching I haven't been able to find how to get the Parse installation object Id as I don't understand how to access it, so I'm resorting to asking you nice people to show me an example in Swift. Once I can get the Id# then I'll look into how to save it as a cookie.

Normally I've always been able to track down either something I can use, adapt or learn from, but in this case I seem to be hitting a brick wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You looked at NSHTTPCookie?

Comment: @kittybangtango Just FYI, when you make an edit to your own question it's a good idea to log in first. Otherwise your edit gets placed in a queue to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?

```
PFInstallation.currentInstallation().objectId!
```

Here's the full code. It makes sure you're already registered:

```
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (isSuccess, hasError) -> Void in
            if isSuccess{
                println("registered!")
                println("Parse Installation Id: \(PFInstallation.currentInstallation().objectId!)")
            }else{
                println("Error: \(hasError)")
            }
        }
```

I got the code after checking the api:

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html#//api/name/currentInstallation